# cshtml image link clickable area too big

Tags: c#, css, razor

I have an image that's serving as a link. The issue is that the clickable region is much larger than the image itself. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
 <a target="_blank" href="http://my.ge.com"><img class="logo" src="../Content/images/always_on_logo.jpg"></a>

 <style type="text/css">
 img.logo {
 display: block;
 margin-left: 351px;
 margin-right: 351px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 135px;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: remove display:block;...

Answer (score 1):

Remove display:block;

```css
 img.logo {
     margin-left: 351px;
     margin-right: 351px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 135px;
 }
```

```html
 <a target="_blank" href="http://my.ge.com">
     <img class="logo" src="../Content/images/always_on_logo.jpg" />
</a>
```